# How can I use a *.d.ts outside of the node_modules folder for my Angular library?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, package, angular8

I have an angular 8 library I'm creating and it's going to utilize the insane.js npm package.  Because insane is JavaScript, I need to make it so that my typescript service recognizes the insane function.  I used dts-gen to create an insane.d.ts file as there is no @types/insane package.  However, I can't use the import in my service unless I place the insane.d.ts file within the /node_modules/insane/ folder.  That said, I'm at a loss on how to put this file in with my code and recognize the insane function.  Every time I move the file out of that directory, I receive an error on my import line saying:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'insane'. 'c:/TFS/repo/amrock-simple-mde/projects/simple-mde/node_modules/insane/insane.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

I've provided a stackblitz link [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wgebwd) to help describe what I'm experiencing.  I hope it helps.  Check out the SanitizerService under the shared folder to get an idea of what I was trying to do.  I'm trying to do something to the effect of:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as insane from 'insane';  // line where error is

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SanitizerService {

  constructor() { }

  sanitize(content: string): string {
    return insane(content, {
     allowedAttributes: {
       a: ['name', 'target']
     }
   });
  }

}
```

I'd expect the import to recognize the insane.d.ts, but it doesn't. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a [`declare module` statement](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules) for this:

```js
declare module 'insane' {
   // ...
}
```

Essentially wrap your whole `.d.ts` file in the `declare module` block and remove all existing `declare` keywords since those are not valid inside a `declare module` block.

Secondly, make sure that the `.d.ts` file is included by TypeScript. Usually the easiest way to do this is to specify it in the `include` option of your `tsconfig.json`.

[Updated Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gfkssh)

Comment: Your solution is very close, but it's getting the following error:

ERROR TypeError: insane is not a function
    at SanitizerService.sanitize (sanitizer.service.ts:25)
    at AppComponent.ngOnInit (app.component.ts:23)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (provider.ts:212)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (view.ts:429)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (view.ts:389)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (services.ts:431)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (services.ts:392)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)

Comment: That's a runtime error, meaning it has nothing directly to do with the type declarations. My guess is the module wants to be imported differently. Usually it helps to use a debugger or log to find out what the value of `insane` is. You can also try importing the default export: `import insane from 'insane';`